# Remove untype caught error, cannot read property of toLocaleString this is error

Tags: javascript, typeerror, undefined

// ExpenseDate Component

```
function ExpenseDate(props){
    const month=props.date.toLocaleString("en-us",{month:"long"})
let day=props.date.toLocaleString("en-us",{day:"2-digit"})
let year=props.date.getFullYear()
return(
    <div>
        <div>{month}</div>
        <div>{day}</div>
        <div>{year}</div>
    </div>
)
}
export default ExpenseDate;
```

Error showing in browser console

[image]

Comment: So prop is not set so look to see if it exists before you use it.

Comment: `if(props.date) {....} else { return 'something else'}`